# Flutter catch overflow exceptions in release mode

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Is there any way to catch flutter overflow exceptions in release mode? I'd like to log errors in screen building and send them to firebase crashlytics, for example.

In debug mode, all overflow errors are properly caught by firebase crashlytics, but in release mode, those errors are not reported.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "try{ //your code} catch(error) {//send error to firebase crashlytics} it must work

Comment: yes, it works, but I'd have to add this try-catch block in all screens.. Actually, I'm setting FlutterError.onError function to send me errors reports. But it is working only on debug mode.